# Parameter expansion question

Tags: bash, scripting, macintosh

I have 2 files each in user/admin/1/2/[a-c] subdirectories.

The files are preQC_1.txt and preQC_2.txt - both of which will be inputs in my tool.

I use "${f##*/}" for preQC_1.txt in my for loop

```
for f in ~/1/2/*/*_1.txt; do exptool input1= "${f##*/}" input2= "{$f%_1.txt}_2.txt"
```

My program says that file '{$f%_1.txt}_2.txt' and I am 100% sure I am incorrectly using parameter expansion. For input2, how can I make sure I am ONLY getting the 'preQC_2.txt' (filename+extension without the directory listing)?

EDIT: I've tried combining "${f##*/}" and {$f%_1.txt}_2.txt" but that actually expands to 'user/admin/1/2/a/preQC_1.txt_2.txt'

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "My program says that file '{$f%_1.txt}_2.txt' and I am 100% sure I am incorrectly using parameter expansion.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for f in ~/1/2/*/*_1.txt; do
    file_without_path="${f##*/}"
    exptool input1= "${file_without_path}" input2= "${file_without_pathf%_1.txt}_2.txt"
done
```

Comment: you forgot the `$` character in `input2`'s definition :)

Answer (score 1):

You just made a syntax mistake: you wrote `"{$f%_1.txt}_2.txt"` while the correct form is `"${f%_1.txt}_2.txt"` (you misplaced the `$` character).
 :)
Edit: woops, I got it wrong, because in the block `"${f%_1.txt}_2.txt"`, `f`'s value is still `user/admin/1/2/a/preQC_1.txt` so basically `"${f%_1.txt}_2.txt"`'s value is `user/admin/1/2/a/preQC_2.txt`, which is not what you desire.
I'd recommend updating `f`'s value in the first place, like

```
for f in ~/1/2/*/*_1.txt
f=${f##*/}
do exptool input1= "$f" input2= "${f%_1.txt}_2.txt"
done
```

which pretty much joins Hauke Laging's answer.